# Win32 Events -- I need to be notified when the event is cleared

Tags: multithreading, winapi

Win 7, x64, Visual Studio Community 2015, C++

I have a thread which I need to pause/unpause or terminate, which I currently do with manually-reset "run" or "kill" events.  The loop in the thread pauses each time for 5000ms.

My goal is to be able to stop waiting or kill the thread while in the middle of the wait.

The problem is the way I currently have it set up, I need to be notified when the "run" event goes to the non-signalled state, but there is no way to do this, unless I create an event with the inverted polarity, but this seems like a kludge.  In short, I need a level-sensitive signal, not edge sensitive.

Maybe the event should just toggle the run state?

This is the thread function:

```
DWORD WINAPI DAQ::_fakeOutFn(void *param) {
    DAQ *pThis = (DAQ *)param;
    const DWORD timeout = 5000;

    bool running = false;
    HANDLE handles[] = { pThis->hFakeTaskRunningEvent, pThis->hFakeTaskKillEvent };

    do {
        DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        switch (result) {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0: // Run started or continued
            running = true;
            pThis->outputIndex++;
            if (pThis->outputIndex >= pThis->numSamples)
                pThis->outputIndex = 0;
            // Wait here
            // Not sure how to cancel this if the TaskRunningEvent goes false during the wait
            DWORD result2 = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, timeout);
            // Check result2, and 'continue' the loop if hFakeTaskRunningEvent went to NON-SIGNALLED state
            break;
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: // Kill requested
            running = false;
            break;
        default:
            _ASSERT_EXPR(FALSE, L"Wait error");
            break;
        }
    } while (running);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A condition variable may work better here.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate events for the running and resume states.  Then you can reset the resume event to pause, and signal the event to resume.  The running event should be used to let the thread know when it has work to do, not when it should pause that work for a period of time.

```
DWORD WINAPI DAQ::_fakeOutFn(void *param)
{
    DAQ *pThis = (DAQ *)param;

    bool running = false;
    HANDLE handles[] = { pThis->hFakeTaskRunningEvent, pThis->hFakeTaskKillEvent };

    do
    {
        DWORD result = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        switch (result)
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0: // Run started
            {
                running = true;
                pThis->outputIndex++;
                if (pThis->outputIndex >= pThis->numSamples)
                    pThis->outputIndex = 0;

                // check for pause here
                HANDLE handles2[] = { pThis->hFakeTaskResumeEvent, pThis->hFakeTaskKillEvent };
                DWORD result2 = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles2, FALSE, INFINITE);
                switch (result2)
                {
                    case WAIT_OBJECT_0;
                        break;

                    case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: // Kill requested
                        running = false;
                        break;

                    default:
                        _ASSERT_EXPR(FALSE, L"Wait error");
                        break;
                }

                if (!running) break;

                // continue working...

                break;
            }

            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: // Kill requested
                running = false;
                break;

            default:
                _ASSERT_EXPR(FALSE, L"Wait error");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (running);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here i be use not Events, but queue Apc to this thread with 'command' (run,pause,exit). however need know more about task, for select best solution. you writing service ?

```
struct DAQ 
{
    HANDLE _hEvent;

    enum STATE {
        running,
        paused,
        exit
    } _state;

    DAQ()
    {
        _hEvent = 0;
    }

    ~DAQ()
    {
        if (_hEvent)
        {
            ZwClose(_hEvent);
        }
    }

    NTSTATUS Init()
    {
        return ZwCreateEvent(&_hEvent, EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, 0, NotificationEvent, FALSE);
    }

    void Close()
    {
        if (HANDLE hEvent = InterlockedExchangePointer(&_hEvent, 0))
        {
            ZwClose(hEvent);
        }
    }

    DWORD fakeOutFn()
    {
        DbgPrint("running\n");
        _state = running;
        ZwSetEvent(_hEvent, 0);
        static LARGE_INTEGER Interval = { 0, MINLONG };
        do ; while (0 <= ZwDelayExecution(TRUE, &Interval) && _state != exit);

        DbgPrint("exit\n");
        return 0;
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI _fakeOutFn(PVOID pThis)
    {
        return ((DAQ*)pThis)->fakeOutFn();
    }

    void OnApc(STATE state)
    {
        _state = state;

        static PCSTR stateName[] = { "running", "paused" };

        if (state < RTL_NUMBER_OF(stateName))
        {
            DbgPrint("%s\n", stateName[state]);
        }
    }

    static void WINAPI _OnApc(PVOID pThis, PVOID state, PVOID)
    {
        ((DAQ*)pThis)->OnApc((STATE)(ULONG_PTR)state);
    }
};

void test()
{
    DAQ d;
    if (0 <= d.Init())
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, DAQ::_fakeOutFn, &d, 0, 0))
        {
            if (STATUS_SUCCESS == ZwWaitForSingleObject(d._hEvent, FALSE, 0))// need for not QueueApc too early. in case ServiceMain this event not need
            {
                d.Close();
                int n = 5;
                do 
                {
                    DAQ::STATE state;
                    if (--n)
                    {
                        state = (n & 1) != 0 ? DAQ::running : DAQ::paused;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state = DAQ::exit;
                    }
                    ZwQueueApcThread(hThread, DAQ::_OnApc, &d, (PVOID)state, 0);
                } while (n);
            }
            ZwWaitForSingleObject(hThread, FALSE, 0);
            ZwClose(hThread);
        }
    }
}
```